# 32 bit number handling with ATTiny and Atmel Studio

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc, atmelstudio, attiny

I am wondering how the ATTiny, specifically the ATTiny24 stores 32 bit unsigned ints in memory.  I'm trying to take a 32 bit value and write it to a 32 bit location in the EEPROM.  I have attempted to use a simple mask, but every time I try, I get the lower two bytes (lsb) correctly and the upper two bytes are all zeros.  For example, when I try to write: 0x12345678 the output is: 0x00005678.  Is there a setting in Atmel Studio I need to set, or do I need to use another method other than masking.

Ultimately I want to be able to read a 32 bit counter value and write it to a specific location in the EEPROM.  I am working on modifying an existing circuit and thus do not have the luxury to debug with a serial output.

Code Snippets:

In main:

```
unsigned long test_val = 305419896;  //0x12345678
EEprom_Long_Write(0x25,test_val);
```

Functions:

EEprom_Long_Write:

```
void EEprom_Long_Write(unsigned char eeadr, unsigned long EE_Data)
{
    unsigned char temp=0;
    unsigned char count= eeadr + 3;
    unsigned long mask=0;
    unsigned char position=24;  
    while (eeadr <= count)
    {
        mask = ((1<<8)-1) << position;
        temp = (EE_Data & mask) >> position;
        EEPROM_write(eeadr, temp);
        position = position-8;
        eeadr++;
    }
}
```

EEPROM_write:

```
void EEPROM_write(unsigned char ucAddress, unsigned char ucData)
{   
    while(EECR & (1<<EEPE));        //Wait for completion of previous write
    EECR =(0<<EEPM1) | (0>>EEPM0);  // Set Programming mode
    EEARL = ucAddress;              // Setup address and data registers
    EEDR = ucData;                  // Load Data Register
    EECR |= (1<<EEMPE);             // Write logical one to EEMPE
    EECR |= (1<<EEPE);              // Start eeprom write be setting EEPE

}
```

Comment: Use `stdint.h` types, not the built-in names to have types with defined width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fell into the pit of [*integer promotion* and coercion](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1). `((1<<8)-1)` is processed as `int`, not `long` (better: `uint32_t`). On AVR, `int` has the minimum size allowed by the standard: 16 bits.

As is is anyway too complicated, you can use the following:

```
uint8_t shift = 32U;   // enough is enough
do {
    shift -= 8U;
    EEPROM_write(eeadr++, (uint8_t)(EE_Data >> shift));
} while ( shift ) ;
```

This safes you one additional shift and the explicit masking and some registers.

Note my use of `stdint.h` types (you have to include the header, of course). You should correct all declarations accordingly. The cast to `uint8_t` implies masking.

Comment: Thanks for that!  Would I also need to change my function definition to `void EEprom_Long_Write(unsigned char eeadr, uint32_t EE_Data)` ?

Comment: @soupaloop: You should always use the proper types. If `eeadr` is guaranteed to be less than 256, use `uint8_t`, else `uint16_t`, etc. Read about `stdint.h` (Wikipedia, or the linked standard). Hmm, I will edit my answer, `shift` should be `uint8_t` on AVR actually (sorry, I'm more used to ARM now, where 32 bits are standard). And: **please** read the linked text! This is **vital**.

Comment: @soupaloop: If my answer solved your problem, you should consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
mask = ((1<<8)-1) << position;
temp = (EE_Data & mask) >> position;
```

to this:

```
temp = (EE_Data >> position) & 0xFF;
```